# Lutris not starting

Tags: 20.04, error-handling, lutris

I installed Lutris on my Ubuntu 20.04 with the instructions on their website - https://lutris.net/downloads/
The app is installed on my laptop but when I search for it and click on it, it does not open anything up.
When I try to run it from terminal using the command "lutris", this is what I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/games/lutris", line 54, in <module>
from lutris.gui.application import Application # pylint: disable=no-name-in-module
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lutris/gui/application.py", line 53, in <module>
from .lutriswindow import LutrisWindow
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lutris/gui/lutriswindow.py", line 26, in <module>
from lutris.gui.widgets.sidebar import LutrisSidebar
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lutris/gui/widgets/sidebar.py", line 6, in <module>
from lutris import platforms, runners, services
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lutris/platforms.py", line 19, in <module>
_init_platforms()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lutris/platforms.py", line 14, in _init_platforms
runner = runners.import_runner(runner_name)()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lutris/runners/wine.py", line 229, in __init__
"default": dxvk.DXVKManager().version,
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lutris/util/wine/dxvk.py", line 56, in version
return self.versions[0]
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lutris/util/wine/dxvk.py", line 45, in versions
self._versions = self.load_dxvk_versions()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lutris/util/wine/dxvk.py", line 65, in load_dxvk_versions
with open(versions_path, "r") as dxvk_version_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/syphoonfi/.local/share/lutris/runtime/dxvk/dxvk_versions.json'
```

Any clues or noticable errors?
What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your terminal, make sure you're in your home directory then run this command...

```
wget https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/538903130704838656/796102070825779250/dxvk_versions.json -P $HOME/.local/share/lutris/runtime/dxvk
```

Comment: Thank you so much William!
After installing this Lutris is running.
As of being a new user to Ubuntu and Linux in general, I was wondering, how could I have known that I need to use this command by my own?